# How to update room database based on server response

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

I am fetching data from server and saving in room database and then from room showing it in recycler view.Data is perfectly saving in room database and showing in recycler view.

**Problem:** When I am deleting some data from server database then its old copy that saved earlier still persists in room.

**What I want:** I don't want to show data deleted from server in recycler view.So how can I update room database based on server response.

This is what I have done so far:

**UserDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void Insert(User... users);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers();
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users")
public class User {

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
private String id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "age")
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;

public User(String id,String name, String age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

private Context context;
private UserDb userDb;
private LiveData<List<User>> listLiveData;

public UserRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    userDb = UserDb.getInstance(context);
    listLiveData = userDb.userDao().getRoomUsers();
}

public void getUserList(){

          Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
          ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

          Call<List<User>> userList = apiService.getUser();

          userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, final Response<List<User>> response) {

                  Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() throws Exception {

                              if(response.body() != null) {

                                  List<User> list = response.body();

                                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                                      String id = list.get(i).getId();
                                      String names = list.get(i).getName();
                                      String age = list.get(i).getAge();

                                      User user = new User(id,names,age);

                                      userDb.userDao().Insert(user);


                                  }

                              }

                          }
                      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                                Toast.makeText(context,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(context,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });

}

public LiveData<List<User>> getRoomUsers(){

    return listLiveData;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

UserRepository userRepository;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
UserViewModel userModel;
List<User> userList;
UserAdapter adapter;
ProgressBar prg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    prg = findViewById(R.id.prg);

    userRepository = new UserRepository(this);
    userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    userList = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new UserAdapter(userList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    userModel.getListLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<User> users) {

            prg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adapter.setUserList(users);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddUser.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



    userRepository.getUserList();
}
```

Someone please let me know how can I get desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRoomUsers()` to get a list of known users from the repository in `onResponse()`.

For each user in `response.body()`, check if it has a corresponding list item in the known users' list. Remove this item.

Afterwards, the list of known users will contain only users which have been deleted from the server. So for each of these remaining users, you can delete them from the room database.

The following code snippet shows how to find the users which are currently not known to the server:

```
if (response.body() != null) {

    List<User> list = response.body();
    List<User> previouslyKnownUsers = new ArrayList<>(userDb.userDao().getRoomUsers().getValue());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String id = list.get(i).getId();
        String names = list.get(i).getName();
        String age = list.get(i).getAge();

        User user = new User(id, names, age);

        userDb.userDao().Insert(user);

        User knownUser = null; 
        for(User previouslyKnownUser: previouslyKnownUsers){
            if(previouslyKnownUser.getId().equals(user.getId())){
                knownUser = previouslyKnownUser;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(knownUser != null){
            previouslyKnownUsers.remove(knownUser);
        }
    }

    for(User currentlyUnknownUser: previouslyKnownUsers){
        userDb.userDao().Delete(currentlyUnknownUser);
    }
}
```

In order to make it work, you have to add a method `Delete(User user)` in `UserDao.java`

Comment: How do I implement this in code could you please post some code.

Comment: @Digvijay - will do tomorrow (it's getting a bit late around here) One question: are two users equal (not in Java but in the real world) if they have the same id?

Comment: @Digvijay - added a code snippet. I assume two user instances refer to the same "real" user if they have the same id

Comment: When I am trying to implement your solution. Here ``List<User> previouslyKnownUsers = new ArrayList<>(userDb.userDao().getRoomUsers().getValue());`` it is saying  ``Attempt to invoke interface method java.lang.objec[] java.util.Collection.toArray[] on a null object reference.``

Comment: @Digvijay - this sounds as if something inside of the method getRoomUsers() does "not work". Sorry but I don't know how to help you there since I don't have access to your full code. I only can show you how to deal with the list which should be returned by getRoomUsers() if everything works as intended